# Flexbox style "justify-content: space-between" misaligned in Firefox with absolutely positioned child

Tags: css, flexbox

Have an issue with **Flexbox** and **space-between** in Firefox 36. For reasons unknown space-between is not correct in Firefox (causing the strange margin on left) but perfect in Google Chrome.

[Chrome screen capture](http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah149/michael_roth1/st-chrome_zpsi6bfes6v.png)

[Firefox screen capture](http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah149/michael_roth1/st_zpsmnbzivff.jpg)

**CSS**

```
  .form-status {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; 
  position: relative;

  &:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: $gray;
  }

  .step {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
    color: $gray-light;

    &:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      height: 8px;
      width: 8px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      top: -11px;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -11px;
      background: $gray;
      border: 8px solid #0c0616;
      box-sizing: content-box;
    }

    &:first-child, &:last-child {
      &:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: -100vw;
        right: 0;
        height: 1px;
        background: black;
      }
    }
    &:first-child:before { right: 50%; }
    &:last-child:before { left: 50%; }

    &.active {
      color: white;
      &:after { background: $brand-yellow; }
    }
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="page-section page-section-dark page-section-narrow">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-status">
            <div class="step {{#ifeq step "one"}}active{{/ifeq}}">
                Basic Information
            </div>
            <div class="step {{#ifeq step "two"}}active{{/ifeq}}">
                Agreement
            </div>
            <div class="step {{#ifeq step "three"}}active{{/ifeq}}">
                Payment
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try adding vendor prefixes?

Comment: Nope - might be worth a shot.

Comment: Vendor prefixes won't help you; Firefox doesn't support prefixes for modern CSS flexbox (or much of anything, except for a few legacy properties/values).

Comment: (1) do you have a live testcase / demo? It's hard to debug from a screenshot and inactive source.  (2) Are you sure the `space-between` is actually the problem? (Are Firefox & Chrome consistent if you remove that?)  (3) Does it work if you add the CSS rule `* { min-width:0}` ? (You really want a more targeted rule than that, but that'll tell you whether this is the most common Firefox vs. Chrome flexbox difference that I see, which is due to Chrome not yet having fixed https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=426898 )

Comment: @dholbert yes I do have a live URL. Where can I message you with the URL? Actually I think there is a bug but I have not been able to find much documentation. I did read somewhere that there was a change between versions 34 and 35 I believe that could be the source of this bug.

Comment: Ah, is the URL non-public? Sure, you can email it to me at [my same username] at mozilla dot com. And yeah, the "min-width" change I mentioned above is probably the change you read about (though it was actually new in Firefox 34, not in 35).

Comment: Thanks - email sent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue is from this styling on your final page:

```
.form-status:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:1px;
    background:#555
}
```

(which I think comes from the "&:before" in your original question).

`.form-status` is a flex container, and this is giving it an absolutely-positioned child -- and absolute positioning for children of flex containers [doesn't quite work interoperably yet](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Feb/0411.html) -- apparently IE (or their next-gen "Spartan") is the only browser to implement the latest spec-text on that right now.

This styling breaks your layout because the absolutely positioned child drops an invisible 0-sized "placeholder", which forms a 0-sized flex item, and that flex item affects the positioning of all the other flex items via participating in the `space-around` alignment.  (This was required by an [earlier version of the flexbox spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120612/#abspos-flex-items), but it's changed to no longer call for these placeholders to form flex items.)

I'm intending to bring Firefox up-to-date* on this aspect of flexbox soon ([here's the bug on that](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=874718)), but in the meantime, I'd suggest avoiding using absolute positioning on any direct child of a flexbox, since it works differently in every browser right now.

*(UPDATE: This is [now fixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1269045) in Firefox trunk builds.  The fix will tentatively be in Firefox 52, which I believe ships in March 2017.)